# Сигналы Linux для обработки событий - моветон?

Tags: linux, c, signal

В Linux-системе программа делает `popen()`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли считаться нормальной практикой использовать механизм сигналов, чтобы сообщить некритическую информацию из потомка (в частности, сделать на этой основе обработчик нажатия кнопки)? Это, конечно, плохомасштабируемое решение, пользовательские сигналы быстро закончатся, но может ли оно иметь место при каких-то условиях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не спец в Linux-платформе, но на мой вкус, есть более адекватные средства IPC. Да хотя бы расшарить pipe (один или несколько) с потомком и общаться через него.

А так вообще, всё что решает задачу, соответствует спецификации и не содержит багов есть решение, вне зависимости от его изящества.

Comment: Согласен,  pipe для запланированной передачи данных от потомка к родителю предпочтительней сигналов.

Answer (score 3):

Сигналы могут приходить когда угодно, разрывая код в любом месте. И мутексы не помогают. Нужно очень аккуратно программировать функции, принимающие сигналы. Почитайте **man 7 signal**, в особенности после подзаголовка **Async-signal-safe functiuons**.
Также сигналы можно принимать через файловый дескиптор, но зачем городить, если есть pipe.

Многие демоны и некоторые утилиты (например dd) принимают SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, SIGHUP для управления (перечитать конфиг, выдать статистику).

Comment: Спасибо за участие в обсуждении. Сигналы, действительно, достаточно беспардонно перехватывают управление наподобие аппаратных прерываний, что для штатного обмена данными между процессами, как мне кажется, не подходит.

Comment: @LXA, [man sigprocmask](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) (и остальные, связанные с ним) почитайте, раз уж заинтересовались сигналами.

Дело в том, что существует такая штука -- маска сигналов потока (процесса), которая позволяет блокировать доставку сигнала (скажу сразу, сигналы не накапливаются) и получать их только в нужных местах программы.

Хотя, как я уже писал в комментарии, от программирования передачи информации с помощью сигналов больше головной боли, нежели пользы (pipe или другой канал вместе с poll/epoll/select обычно программируются проще для **работы с потомками**).

Comment: Ловить сигнал лучше по sigaction, там можно маску менять на время выполнения перехватывающей функции. Сигналы не накапливаются, а сливаются в один, т.е. всё таки придёт сигнал после разблокирования, это не касается Real-time signals, они придут все в том же порядке и можно ещё данные передать, но одно число int или указатель. Правда непонятно что делать с указателем в другом процессе.
При получении можно ещё попытаться узнать кто послал сигнал, но отправитель может быть уже завершился.

Answer (score 2):

> чтобы сообщить некритическую
> информацию

IMHO, для этих целей гораздо проще и адекватнее использовать механизм сообщений (POSIX или System-V).Да и именованые каналы (pipe) отлично для этого подходят.

Comment: У сигнала одно маленькое преимущество, его легко можно послать из шелла командой kill